# Como instalar driver do sqlsrv no pdo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdo

Como faço para instalar ou sqlsrv driver no pdo?

```
<?php
function conectar(){

$pdo = null;
try {
    $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server;host=192.168.0.30\COMPASS;dbname=weset;", "sa","Cabilog2015@", $opcoes);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
return $pdo;
}

conectar();
?>
```

Estou recebendo essa mensagem no navegador:

> could not find driver

Comment: No dsn da PDO está mysl e você quer habilitar sqlsrv? Afinal SQL Server ou MySQL?

Comment: Alterei.
Mas já consegui.
Eu não tinha desabilitado a dll do php.ini